# MVC 4 Child Model Create and Edit views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I got 2 Models with 1-1 relationship.

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AddressModel Address { get; set; }
}

public class AddressModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need a view that I can link the Address model with the customer, so, in the create of the customerModel, it bring the address create too, and linked, like in the post the address will be in the customer field.

Comment: Create a strongly typed view for your `CustomerModel` and you can access the `Address` information from the `Customer`.

Comment: Like @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.Street);
?
And how to create the address, like if I do that it will say its null

Answer (score 0):

```
@model Mvc.Models.CustomerModel


@Html.EditorForModel(Model)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address)
```

If you create your view like that, you will then able to post back to an action result that takes a `CustomerModel` and the binding should work correctly

You'll probably want to do a bit more with custom annotations etc. as I doubt you'll want the user to be able to edit the Address id, but that should point you in the right direction

Comment: So I can put EditorFor Address without going field by field?
Or should I put EditorFor(x => x.Address.Street) ??

Comment: If this is purely for creation, so you don't need to know the Id of an existing address, then yes, EditorFor(X => x.Address.Street) should work for you

Comment: And it will be linked to Model.Address right?
If I want to edit, without messing with the id, it will work too?

Comment: You will have to output the id as well, otherwise it will get lost when you post back to the server. Without trying to be rude, it sounds like you need to go and read up a bit more on MVC and how to get to grips with views, models and bindings